# Adding char to string produces crash in C++

Tags: c++, string, crash, char, append

I have this public function inside a class and what I am doing is appending a string to another string char by char (because I'm also making some checking on the characters). So, it basically looks like this:

```
void mystring::copy(wstring oldtext) {
    wstring newtext;
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<oldtext.length(); ++i) {
        // Doing some checking ...
        // I also used newtext.append(1, oldtext[i]);
        newtext += oldtext[i];
        // Just testing
        wprintf_s(L"String: %s\n", newtext);
    }
}
```

So, if I comment the `wprintf_s` line the program doesn't crash, but if I want to test and see what is added to *newtext* by using it, it crashes. I tried to add `"\0\n"` but it doesn't work either and it smells like some pointer problem. What could it be?

Comment: You're passing a class object to a variadic C function (`wprintf_s`); that's not a good idea.

Comment: That's just for testing. I will remove it. Maybe I should use another function for that, then

Comment: @ali, `std::wcout << "String: " << newtext << "\n";`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you should use `newtext.c_str()` to convert it to a normal C string when using it with `%s` type specifier inside a `printf`.